# ez-vcard library not working with modular java applications

Tags: java, package, dependencies, vcf-vcard

I am having issue with importing ez-vcard library in a java (17) application which is modular one. IDE I am using is IntelliJ Idea. The error shows up like below.

[image]

The library is great but while migrating from Java 8 to Modular Java Development, The package name and module name are mismatching, that is resulting into -> ide not able to find the package. Also the dependency can not be imported in project to build/compile a modular java application.

Please show me some way, how to get this working.